# How to split a C program by its function blocks?

Tags: python, regex, pycparser

I am trying to split a C program by its function blocks. For example,

I tried using regex library and try to split by `(){`. But of no use. Not sure where to begin.

```
string = """
int firt(){
    if () { 

    }
}

customtype second(){
    if () { 

    }
    for(){

    }
}
fdfndfndfnlkfe
    """
```

And I want the result to be a list that has each of the function block as an element: `['int first(){ ... }', 'customtype second(){....}']`

I tried the following but getting `None`

```
import regex
import re

reg = r"""^[^()\n]+\([^()]*\)\s*
\{
    (?:[^{}]*|(?R))+
\}"""

print(regex.match(reg, string))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: don't - use a parser instead.
Second, if you insist and to see *why* should use a parser instead, have a glimpse at this recursive approach (which will only work with the newer `regex` module):

```
^[^()\n]+\([^()]*\)\s*
\{
    (?:[^{}]*|(?R))+
\}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rph0Rf/1/). This will break with [**comments that include curly braces**](https://regex101.com/r/rph0Rf/2).

---

In `Python` this would be

```
import regex as re

reg = re.compile(r"""^[^()\n]+\([^()]*\)\s*
\{
    (?:[^{}]*|(?R))+
\}""", re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

for function in reg.finditer(string):
    print(function.group(0))
```

Comment: This would work great. I tried it with Python but I m getting `None` as the output. I updated the code. Could you kindly see what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @NewCoder: Added the modified snippet, you need the `verbose` flag.

Comment: shows `re.error: unknown extension ?R at position 41 (line 3, column 16)` ? May I know why?

Comment: @NewCoder: Have you used the exact code from above including `pip install regex` ?

Comment: with regex, it does not produce anything. the output screen looks empty. i.e. it does not even get in the for loop

Comment: @NewCoder: My fault, you need to add the `multiline` flag as well (`re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE`)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing source code is a pretty difficult task. Software like [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) generates source code parsers in C, C++, and Java (C code can be used in Python), but you're unlikely to create a regex to solve this problem (at least easily).